# Using find_in_set() in laravel where clause

Tags: laravel, find-in-set

I know I can use find_in_set as bellow:

```
select `id` from `questions` where FIND_IN_SET(8, categories);
```

But I am using laravel and I would like to write this query there. I have tried this:

```
$q_category = 8;
$object = DB::table("questions")
  ->select('id')
  ->where(DB::RAW("FIND_IN_SET($q_category, categories)"), '!=', null)
  ->get();
```

to get the records that have `8` in their `categories` column (which contains comma seperated category IDs)

But I get records that do not have the category id too.

where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see several potential problems with your current code.  First, you should be binding the `$q_category` value to the call to `FIND_IN_SET`.  Second, the check for a successful call to `FIND_IN_SET` is that the return value is greater than zero, as opposed to non `NULL`.

```
$q_category = 8;
$object = DB::table("questions")
    ->select('id')
    ->whereRaw("FIND_IN_SET(?, categories) > 0", [$q_category])
    ->get();
```