# Php Mysql find in set query /// i want to convert this query in laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder, find-in-set

```
select * from settings where setting_type='admin_privilege' and FIND_IN_SET ('001',`setting_value`) and br_id=4
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using find\_in\_set() in laravel where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55740187/using-find-in-set-in-laravel-where-clause)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
DB::table('settings')
    ->where('setting_type', 'admin_privilege')
    ->where('br_id', 4)
    ->whereRaw("FIND_IN_SET ('001',`setting_value`)")
```